# On exponential generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In an example in my textbook, it is mentioned that the sequence generated by:

${f(x)= e^x + x^2}$

is:  1,1,3,1,1,1,1,...

why is it that when $x^2$ is added to $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i/i!$ we would get 3 as the coefficient of the third term in this sequence?

Comment: We have $x^2=\frac{2}{2!}x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on André's comment: the sequence $(1,1,3,1,1,\ldots)$ is obtained by reading the coefficients of $x^k/k!$, not the coefficients of $x^k$. The coefficient of $x^2/2!$ is 3:
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^x + x^2 &=& x^2 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\\ &=& x^0 + x^1 + 3\frac{x^2}{2!} + \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}.
\end{eqnarray*}